# Why is @napi-rs/canvas not rendering text like it should be?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, html5-canvas

I've been trying to find out how to fix this problem for about 3 hours, and if any one could help, that would be nice.

This is a discord.js project that is using @napi-rs/canvas. for some reason, @napi-rs/canvas is not rendering any text at all.

When the code runs, it gives [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAuCI.png)

I am running this code online, using [railway.app](https://www.railway.app)

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async function(member){
  if (member.guild.id != guildId) return
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(800, 500);
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const pfp = await Canvas.loadImage(member.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"}))
    const bg = await Canvas.loadImage('./joinbg.png')
    const uname = member.user.username
    const dcrim = member.user.discriminator
    console.log(uname+"#"+dcrim+" has joined! sending join img + verification!")
    
    context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff"
    //context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
    context.font = '50px sans-serif'
    context.fillText(""+uname, 200, 100)
    //context.fillText(text, 0, 0)
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(155, 155, 155, 1)'
    context.font = '30px sans-serif'
    context.fillText("#" + dcrim, 200, 140)
    //context.fillText(text2, 0, 0)
    // Pick up the pen
    context.beginPath();

    // Start the arc to form a circle
    context.arc(106.5, 105.5, 92.5, 92.5, Math.PI * 1, true);

    // Put the pen down
    context.closePath();

    // Clip off the region you drew on
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(pfp, 14, 13, 185, 185)

    const a = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('tos')
        .setLabel('View ToS')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
    )

    const newimg = new AttachmentBuilder(await canvas.encode('png'), { name: uname+'#'+dcrim+'-joined.png' })
    client.guilds.fetch("" + process.env.guildid) .then((guild) => {
      guild.channels.fetch("" + process.env.welcomechannelid) .then((channel) => {
        channel.send({ files: [newimg] })
        member.send({
          content: "**Welcome to Plot Block [LIFESTEAL]!**\n\nWe hope you have a good time here!\nPlease click on the button below to begin the first step of the verification process!",
          components: [a]
        })
      })
    })
})
```

I've tried to revert to an old version of @napi-rs/canvas (specifically ^0.1.30)

If you can help, please do.
If you need any more information, i can provide it.

I tried to make a join image that has worked perfectly fine before, but now spectacularly doesn't work when i try to make a new one. The text will not render for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the exact same problem, but I was able to render words after my fix.

The issue here appears to be in the line

```js
context.font = '50px sans-serif'
```

where apparently the phrase `sans-serif` is no longer supported. The package cannot pick a proper font from that phrase, leading to no words being rendered.

To fix this, you can first perform

```js
console.log(GlobalFonts.families);
```

which allows you to see a complete list of the locally supported fonts. It should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    family: 'Arial',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Bahnschrift', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Calibri',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Cambria',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Candara',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaNarrow1', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaNarrow2', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaNarrow3', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaRegular1', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaRegular2', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaRegular3', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaWide1', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaWide2', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Code39AzaleaWide3', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Comic Sans MS',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Comic Neue',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Consolas',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Constantia',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Corbel',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Courier New',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Ebrima', styles: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', styles: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Gabriola', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Gadugi', styles: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { family: 'GenSenRounded TW', styles: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Georgia',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Microsoft Himalaya', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'HoloLens MDL2 Assets', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Impact', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Ink Free', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Javanese Text', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'DFKai-SB', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Leelawadee UI', styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Latin Modern Roman',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Lucida Console', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Malgun Gothic', styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Marlett', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Microsoft Sans Serif', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'MingLiU', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'MingLiU-ExtB', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Myanmar Text', styles: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { family: 'Mongolian Baiti', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'MS Gothic', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Microsoft JhengHei',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    family: 'Microsoft YaHei',
    styles: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { family: 'Microsoft Yi Baiti', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  { family: 'MV Boli', styles: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    family: 'Myriad Pro',
    styles: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },

  ...
```

Notice the `family` field in each of the entries. I typed in a value from this field, and the text could render properly.

For example, you can set the font by the following statement:

```js
context.font = "50px Comic Sans MS";    // `Comic Sans MS` is a value of the `family` field in `GlobalFonts`
```

and the text in our most beloved font will render on the final image.